# How to style a datepicker using nothing but VanillaJS, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I am working on a simple web app using nothing but Vanilla JS, HTML and CSS.

I have created a form, which contains multiple input fields of type "text". Now I want to add a datepicker. I have tried adding an input field of type "date", but I really don't like the design of this datepicker and I haven't found any way of styling the calendar that pops up when clicking into this field.

My first question is: Is there a way to style the calendar of an input field of type "date"?

As I assume the answer to this question is "no", I have searched for an alternative. There are multiple GitHub projects out there, designing a calendar. One example is [this](https://github.com/trananhtuat/js-calendar). This example requires adding the html-code to my webpage. Initially, I wouldn't show the calendar-div, for example by setting its style to `display: none` in my css file. I would have to add a listener- to an input field of type "text" as well and then upon clicking into this field display the calendar. But this would rearrange the input fields below this "datepicker", which I don't want. Is there a way to just display the calendar and let it overlap with its surroundings, for example the input fields below this "datepicker"-field?

I would also appreciate any well known alternatives to styling datepickers with nothing but Vanilla JS, HTML and CSS, if there are any.

Comment: Hi Luk, Can you try this demo?
https://raw.githack.com/mymth/vanillajs-datepicker/v1.2.0/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done your research and the answer is: **No**.

`<input type="date">` or `<input type="datetime-local">` are HTML inputs and its up to the browser vendor (Google, Mozilla, Apple) to decide how to render them.

If you open your dev tools and enable shadow DOM, you can even inspect the nodes created by these inputs but it's not recommended styling them.

It's a Front-end developer's life in 2022 (and perhaps more years to come) to introduce datepicker dependency or create datepicker yourself if you want to have specific look or functionality. From my experience, datepickers are not that hard to make but it's all the corner cases and localized edge cases you have to look out for. So I think it's easier to just go with a dependency.

If you don't want to bring full-fledged framework just for the datepicker then there are various options if you search for them.

You might like modern web components and you could search for date picker created with web components. These do not require any framework, just a supported browser. They usually come with their own stylesheets and JS with ability for some customization, I'd try it out.

Comment: allright, thx a lot for your answer! I'll take a look around what's available then and maybe create my own datepicker.